# Export Time in DBGrid to Excel OLE

Tags: excel, delphi, time, export, ole

i have a trouble in my project.
i want to export my data in dbgrid to excel with ole.

when i export field that contain time (format shorttime hh:mm) to excel, it showing in excel as long date format (MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM).

what i want is it still showing shorttime format (hh:mm) in excel

i have set a number format to hh:mm in my coding but it still showing in long date format.

```
ADOQuery1.First;
x:=1;
while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
begin
  for i:=0 to DBGrid1.FieldCount-1 do
    begin
      XlSheet.cells[2+x,i+1].value:=DBGrid1.Fields[i].Text;
      XlSheet.cells[2+x,i+1].Borders.Weight:=xlThin;
      XlSheet.cells[2+x,i+1].Font.Size:=10;
    end;
    ADOQuery1.Next;
    Inc(x);
  end;
XlSheet.Columns[8].NumberFormat:='hh:mm;@';
```

i'm using database access and data type for that field is Date/Time and ShortTime format.
Sorry for my bad english.
Thank you. :D

Comment: check that date column is actually #8 and not something else. Actually that is rather fragile - little restructuring of DBgrid and it will not work anymore. /// try removing ";@" from the format.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a String to assign a date or numeric Value

Change

```
XlSheet.cells[2+x,i+1].value:=DBGrid1.Fields[i].Text;
```

to

```
XlSheet.cells[2+x,i+1].value:=DBGrid1.Fields[i].Value;
```

Comment: as a sidenote using a VariantArray would be much faster [example implementaion by Ken White](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16642049/1699210)