# Export Delphi to Excel

Tags: excel, wordpress, delphi

This question has been asked several times  ( [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058563/exporting-data-from-a-dbgrid-to-excel)),  One solution comes from here incl. the demo code [Solution from WORDPRESS](https://patlatus.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/delphi-export-to-excel/)

```
ExportRecordsetToMSExcel('D:\x.xls', ADOTable1.Recordset );
```

If I try to compile this code I get this error message :

```
[DCC Fehler]   E2010 Inkompatible Typen: 'ADODB_TLB._Recordset' und 'Winapi.ADOInt._Recordset'
```

What is the reason why I can not compile this code,  how to fix the data mismatch indicated by the compiler error message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a simple type resolution issue. `_Recordset` type is declared in both `ADODB_TLB` and `Winapi.ADOInt` units.

Most probably you don't need `ADODB_TLB` so check your `uses` clauses and remove or comment it out.

In case you need to use both units for some reason, try listing `ADODB_TLB` before `Winapi.ADOInt`. (This could help as the compiler will take the most recent one when resolving unqualified types.)

What definitely works (but might take more effort) is to fully qualify the conflicting types to remove ambiguity, e.g. `Winapi.ADOInt._Recordset`.